# damned facebook comments

Tags: facebook, comments

I'm trying to add facebook comments in my Facebook app. 
In page head ive written all needed metatags. comment divs (trying 2 variants):

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?=ActionBaseDemo::LoadConf( "appUrl" );?>?a=show&demoid=<?=$c['id'] ?>" data-num-posts="5" data-width="300"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?=Facebook::GetConfig( "domain" );?>?m=demo&a=show&demoid=<?=$c['id'] ?>" data-num-posts="5" data-width="300"></div>
```

got 2 warnings:

*Warning: http://apps.facebook.com/appname/?a=show&demoid=32 is unreachable.*
and same warnig
*Warning: `http://mywebsite/?m=demo&a=show&demoid=32` is unreachable.*

What's wrong?

Comment: can you load those sites in your browser and are they publicly accessible?

Comment: Have you tried pointing to https://facebook.com/myfbaccount, yet?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's  exactly what the error message says - Facebook's crawler can't reach your URL - check at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug or manually using CURL with a command like `curl -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" URL_HERE`